# Почему не работает свойство вызывающие метод в объекте

Tags: javascript

```
var user = {
  name: 'Василий',

  sayHi: function() {
    alert( this.name );
  },

  bla: this.sayHi()
};

user.bla();
```

При вызове `user.bla()` выдаёт ошибку:

> sayHi is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в момент создания объекта `user`, `this` - это наружный контекст (`window`, наверное), а не `user`.

И ошибка у Вас возникает не "При вызове user.bla()", а при попытке выполнить строчку

```
bla: this.sayHi()
```

```js
var user = {
  name: 'Василий',

  sayHi: function() {
    alert(this.name);
  },

  bla: function() {
    this.sayHi();
  }
};

user.bla();
```

Через свойство в ES6:

```js
var user = {
  name: 'Василий',

  sayHi: function() {
    alert(this.name);
  },

  get bla() {
    this.sayHi();
  }
};

user.bla;
```

Comment: Я так понял, что это полюбому надо делать через метод, через свойство ни как, да ?